# Visual Studio 2015 / asp.net framework : requiredFieldValidator issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

**PROBLEM :**

1. I have problem with ***RequiredFieldValidator*** in Visual Studio 2015 (ASP.NET).
2. The Problem is ErrorMessage doesn't want to fire whenever i add Text Properties.

---

**Code 1 (With Text Properties):**

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter Your Name" ControlToValidate="Name" CssClass="ErrorMessage" Text="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Before Pressed Button (*No Text Seen*):

> 

After Pressed Button :

> *

**Code 2 (Without Text Properties):**

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter Your Name" ControlToValidate="Name" CssClass="ErrorMessage"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Before Pressed Button (*No Text Seen*):

> 

After Pressed Button :

> Enter Your Name

---

**What i want try to do**

Before Pressed Button :

> *

After Pressed Button :

> Enter Your Name

---

Previously, i had issue with error :

> WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive).

and i got the solution : [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1819175.aspx?Help%20with%20WebForms%20UnobtrusiveValidationMode%20requires%20a%20ScriptResourceMapping%20for%20jquery%20Please%20add%20a%20ScriptResourceMapping%20named%20jquery%20case%20sensitive%20error)

by add the following code :

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
  </appSettings>
```

But, now i'm facing new issue with the text properties.. i don't know what the problems. Any help would be appreciate. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on PageLoad event what you have to do is foreach (RequiredFieldValidator look if Validation==true then change the text to * and show the RequiredFieldValidator..